# How to save data from Cognito Sync to the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.2, amazon-cognito

I have a rails 3.2 server, Android App, our own API and AWS Cognito. Our backend is using PostgreSQL. How do I save the datasets created in cognito sync to our database? Should I listen for the callback of cognito sync's success then save the data using our API? or should I use the aws-sdk at the rails server to get the dataset? I don't want the android app to talk directly to RDS and S3.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use [Cognito Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/cognito-events/) for that: You can set up an Amazon Lambda function that will trigger every time a dataset is updated so you can implement your own logic there.

[Cognito Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/cognito-streams/) would also work, and might be faster because it's async: it makes every dataset update be written to a Kinesis stream, and then you can make your backend consume from that stream.

> Updated as above link was not working.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-events.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-streams.html

Comment: Can I make a post request from the lambda to our server? How can I do that?

Comment: The Lambda is basically a piece of code in the language of your choice, from the supported languages. You can make calls to your service, or directly to RDS/S3 in a similar way you would do it from your backend.

Answer (score 0):

AWS AppSync simplifies application development by letting you create a flexible API to securely access, manipulate, and combine data from one or more data sources. AppSync is a managed service that uses GraphQL to make it easy for applications to get exactly the data they need.

> If you're new to Amazon Cognito Sync, use AWS AppSync. Like Amazon
>   Cognito Sync, AWS AppSync is a service for synchronizing application
>   data across devices.

A single GraphQL API to deliver private and public data. Private data requires authenticated access using authorization mechanisms such as IAM, Amazon Cognito User Pools, and OIDC. Public data does not require authenticated access and is delivered through authorization mechanisms such as API Keys.

[image]

- https://aws.amazon.com//appsync/

You can use aws-amplify to sync

- https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=918861
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/
- https://medium.com/open-graphql/authenticating-an-aws-appsync-graphql-api-with-auth0-48835691810a
- https://hackernoon.com/aws-appsync-queries-and-mutations-with-lambda-2aee303c66b0